# Abrir un PDF desde un button en WPF sin utilizar Syncfusion

Tags: c#, wpf

necesito ayuda con una tarea que parece sencilla y no encuentro por foros.

Estoy desarrollando con WPF C# una aplicación de escritorio, en ella he creado un *button* que al hacer click muestre al usuario la documentación de la aplicación.

El problema es: ¿Cómo puedo abrir un PDF haciendo click en un *button* sin utilizar *using Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer* o *using Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing*?
Para utilizar el paquete de *Syncfusion* me pide un registro que no puedo realizar porque mi Visual Studio es pirata.

¿Alguien sabe hacerlo de un modo diferente?

Este es el *button*:

```
<Canvas>
   <Button Grid.Row = "0" x:Name ="Documentation" Foreground="#FEFB58" FontFamily="Arial Nova Light" 
FontStretch="ExtraExpanded" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" 
Click="Documentation_Click" Content="Guía de usuario" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Canvas.Left="10" 
Canvas.Top="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2,0,34" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClickMode="Press">
       <Button.BindingGroup>
           <BindingGroup/>
       </Button.BindingGroup>
       <Button.Style>
             <Style/>
       </Button.Style>
   </Button>
 </Canvas>
```

Y su evento (este código funciona pero no hace lo que necesito):

```
private void Documentation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.OpenFile = @"C:\Users\...Doc_TST.pdf"; //No es la ruta completa.
            dialog.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".pdf"; // Default file extension
            dialog.Filter = "Text documents (.pdf)|*.pdf"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show open file dialog box
            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            // Process open file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Open document
                string filename = dialog.FileName;
            }
        }
```

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra atención y tiempo.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta ¿al abrir lo abres en visualizador un visualizador en wpf o en el programa por defecto del systema?

Comment: En caso de ser un visualizador hay otras librerias o puedes creartela o buscar alguien que lo haya echo por ejemplo  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413861/add-a-pdf-viewer-to-a-wpf-application

Comment: @rexxarcat quiero abrirlo en visualizador, para que se vea el PDF tal cual está creado :)

Answer (score 0):

Estuve mirando un par de librerías con visualizador que fueran freesource para tu caso , aparte de las que conocía he encontrado que Microsoft ha puesto una libreria para el visualizador web como el edge el cual incluye él para pdf. Que de los que he visto es de lejos el más sencillo de implementar. Si no te vale te haré ejemplos de las otras.

Pasos:

1-Instalar en el nugget package el webview2 de microsoft

2- poner de referencia lo siguiente  `xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"`

3- EL objeto sera Wv2:WebView2 y tienes que assignar el pdf a Source.

Codigo Xaml ejemplo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
       xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row = "0" x:Name ="Documentation" Foreground="#FEFB58" FontFamily="Arial Nova Light" 
FontStretch="ExtraExpanded" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" 
Click="Documentation_Click" Content="Guía de usuario" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Canvas.Left="10" 
Canvas.Top="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2,0,34" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClickMode="Press">
                <Button.BindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup/>
                </Button.BindingGroup>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style/>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
 
        <wv2:WebView2 Grid.Row="1" x:Name="visualizadorpdf"></wv2:WebView2>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codigo C#:

```
 private void Documentation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users";
            //esta comentado por que da error en mi proyecto puede que sea de alguna libreria? substituido por directorio inicial
            //  dialog.OpenFile =@"C:\Users\...Doc_TST.pdf"; //No es la ruta completa.
            dialog.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".pdf"; // Default file extension
            dialog.Filter = "Text documents (.pdf)|*.pdf"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show open file dialog box
            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            // Process open file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Open document
                string filename = dialog.FileName;
                visualizadorpdf.Source=new Uri(filename);
            }
        }
```

Resultado (cree un pdf random para esto):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incongruencias que vi en el codigo:

-Canvas en el que el botton l'he assignas un grid.Row, por eso canvie el canvas por grid

-OpenFileDialog el normal no tiene OpenFile como propiedad es de una libreria o alguna versión mas moderna que la que suelo utilizar, a parte por que abres un selector si le passas el fitchero a mano, por eso lo cambie por un Initial Directory.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Pd funciona como el visualzador web del edge por lo que acarrea sus pros y contras

Comment: lo primero de todo, muchísimas gracias por tu dedicación y tiempo. 

Es un avance lo que me has pasado porque no peta, una vez selecciono un pdf, no hace nada. Esto creo que será porque en mi máquina no hay edge (nos prohibieron utilizarlo en el trabajo).

Comment: Si requiere edge  esta solucion